# Powershell Export-csv autosize cells

Tags: powershell

```
$info =@()
$info += get-aduser -f {filter -and
   Filter...etc} -properties *
For each ($user in $info){
  $exporting =[pscustomobject]@{
    Obj1=$info.property
    ...etc
  }

$export += $exportinfo}

$Export | export-csv "file path" -notypeinfo..etc
```

Keep in mind this is a small portion of a 300+ line script I have going.

It works perfectly how I want it to. However, I would like to know how to autosize the cells in thr csv file.

Comment: There are no *cells*. There are *data values*, and they don't have a defined size. A CSV file is simply a text file that contains data values separated by commas, sometimes quoted (particularly if the data value contains a comma). There's nothing to *size*. (CSV means *Comma Separated Values*.)

Comment: It looks and acts just like a excel spreadsheet though.

Comment: Not until you open it in Excel, which is what does the autosizing. Open it in Notepad (or any other text editor). Don't confuse *storage* with *presentation*.

Comment: Gotcha, gotcha.  I label the extension as .csv in the exports filepath so I figured it went to excel automatically. So is there not a way to incorperate autosizing the cells in the document once it's been created then? Maybe covert cvs to excel then go from there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @KenWhite mentioned, a CSV file is just a text document, and opening in Excel does not autosize the cells.

Using the function at this link, you can convert a CSV file to an XLSX document with the columns autosized.

https://github.com/gangstanthony/PowerShell/blob/master/Save-CSVasExcel.ps1

Example:

```
get-process explorer | export-csv c:\temp\process.csv -notypeinformation
Save-CSVasExcel c:\temp\process.csv
start c:\temp\process.xlsx
```

Comment: This is not the fast solution, see my response.